# Connect Domain Name to VPS - no nameservers

Tags: networking, domain-name-system

I have a VPS from Virpus running Ubuntu 18.04 that I want to use to host a website. I have the Apache server already set up. I purchased a domain name from Namecheap. Now I need to set it up so that the domain name points to my server.

I thought it would be a simple task of adding the nameservers to my dashboard on Namecheap, so I went to my Virpus dashboard to locate the nameserver addresses. I wasn't able to find them, however, so I contacted Virpus support. They told me they don't offer a DNS service so I'd have to set this up with my domain registrar.

So now I'm not sure what to do. I know it must be possible but I'm really new to this kind of stuff. What's the next step?

Comment: You need to log into your `namecheap` admin panel and search for something that says `nameserver` or `DNS` and set the name to IP resolution there (as suggested by Virpus, `namecheap` is your domain registrar)

Comment: Namecheap gives you free DNS service with each domain. Why don't you just use that?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Oh I didn't realize that was free! I thought you only got that if you used Namecheap as a hosting provider. I'll give it a shot and re-post if I get stuck. Thanks!

Comment: And have you managed to set it up?

Comment: For the most part. I set up A records to point my domain and subdomains to the server's IP but I'm having trouble getting the correct pages to display. I suppose that an issue with Apache though, and not DNS.

Answer (score 0):

Based off of Michael Hampton's comment on the original post, I used Namecheap's BasicDNS and created A records for the domain and subdomains and pointed them to the server's IP. After a few hours, the DNS cache updated and it seems to be working now.

Namecheap has some pretty good [documentation](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/319/2237/how-can-i-set-up-an-a-address-record-for-my-domain).